# Windows installer crashes when running MSI - Win 2003

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

Windows installer service is crashing everytime I try to install any MSI on a Windows 2003 server.

The problem is not isolated to one MSI but any MSI.

I upgraded to the latest version Windows Installer 4.5 (x86).

The MSI I built is also compiled against the x86 platform.

I have attached the output from the MSI log when I tried it from CMD.

```
 === Verbose logging started: 2/23/2011  12:32:31  Build type: SHIP UNICODE 4.05.6001.00  Calling process: C:\WINDOWS\system32\msiexec.exe 
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:085]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:085]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 1
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:085]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: c:\X2SecurityReCalculatorSetup.msi
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:085]: Machine policy value 'DisableUserInstalls' is 0
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:101]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: Verifying package --> 'c:\X2SecurityReCalculatorSetup.msi' against software restriction policy
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:101]: Note: 1: 2262 2: DigitalSignature 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:101]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: c:\X2SecurityReCalculatorSetup.msi is not digitally signed
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:101]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: c:\X2SecurityReCalculatorSetup.msi is permitted to run at the 'unrestricted' authorization level.
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:116]: Cloaking enabled.
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:116]: Attempting to enable all disabled privileges before calling Install on Server
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: End dialog not enabled
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: Original package ==> c:\X2SecurityReCalculatorSetup.msi
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: Package we're running from ==> c:\DOCUME~1\nazirj\LOCALS~1\Temp\2\253005.msi
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: APPCOMPAT: looking for appcompat database entry with ProductCode '{312994E0-3EF0-4FEF-996E-2C15DAC190D5}'.
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: APPCOMPAT: no matching ProductCode found in database.
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: MSCOREE not loaded loading copy from system32
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: Machine policy value 'TransformsSecure' is 1
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: Note: 1: 2262 2: MsiFileHash 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: Machine policy value 'DisablePatch' is 0
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: Machine policy value 'AllowLockdownPatch' is 0
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: Machine policy value 'DisableLUAPatching' is 0
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: Machine policy value 'DisableFlyWeightPatching' is 0
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: Enabling baseline caching for this transaction since all active patches are MSI 3.0 style MSPs or at least one MSI 3.0 minor update patch is active
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: APPCOMPAT: looking for appcompat database entry with ProductCode '{312994E0-3EF0-4FEF-996E-2C15DAC190D5}'.
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: APPCOMPAT: no matching ProductCode found in database.
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: Transforms are not secure.
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MsiLogFileLocation property. Its value is 'c:\try.log'.
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: Command Line: CURRENTDIRECTORY=C:\WINDOWS\system32 CLIENTUILEVEL=0 CLIENTPROCESSID=3060 
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding PackageCode property. Its value is '{1C92A40E-4708-4C45-96A4-EC25F709EE88}'.
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: Product Code passed to Engine.Initialize:           ''
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: Product Code from property table before transforms: '{312994E0-3EF0-4FEF-996E-2C15DAC190D5}'
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: Product Code from property table after transforms:  '{312994E0-3EF0-4FEF-996E-2C15DAC190D5}'
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: Product not registered: beginning first-time install
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ProductState property. Its value is '-1'.
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: Entering CMsiConfigurationManager::SetLastUsedSource.
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: User policy value 'SearchOrder' is 'nmu'
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: Adding new sources is allowed.
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding PackagecodeChanging property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: Package name extracted from package path: 'X2SecurityReCalculatorSetup.msi'
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: Package to be registered: 'X2SecurityReCalculatorSetup.msi'
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: Note: 1: 2262 2: AdminProperties 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ALLUSERS property. Its current value is '2'. Its new value: '1'.
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: Machine policy value 'DisableMsi' is 1
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: Machine policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 0
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: User policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 0
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: Product installation will be elevated because user is admin and product is being installed per-machine.
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: Running product '{312994E0-3EF0-4FEF-996E-2C15DAC190D5}' with elevated privileges: Product is assigned.
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CURRENTDIRECTORY property. Its value is 'C:\WINDOWS\system32'.
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CLIENTUILEVEL property. Its value is '0'.
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CLIENTPROCESSID property. Its value is '3060'.
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: TRANSFORMS property is now: 
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding VersionDatabase property. Its value is '200'.
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\nazirj\Application Data
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\nazirj\Favorites
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\nazirj\NetHood
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\nazirj\My Documents
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\nazirj\PrintHood
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\nazirj\Recent
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\nazirj\SendTo
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\nazirj\Templates
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\nazirj\Local Settings\Application Data
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\nazirj\My Documents\My Pictures
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\nazirj\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\nazirj\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\nazirj\Start Menu\Programs
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\nazirj\Start Menu
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\nazirj\Desktop
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Templates
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\WINDOWS\Fonts
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: Note: 1: 2898 2: MS Sans Serif 3: MS Sans Serif 4: 0 5: 16 
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: Running install from non-console Terminal Server session.
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: Machine policy value 'EnableAdminTSRemote' is 1
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding Privileged property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\MS Setup (ACME)\User Info 3: 2 
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding USERNAME property. Its value is 'User'.
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\MS Setup (ACME)\User Info 3: 2 
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding COMPANYNAME property. Its value is 'SAHL'.
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding DATABASE property. Its value is 'c:\DOCUME~1\nazirj\LOCALS~1\Temp\2\253005.msi'.
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding OriginalDatabase property. Its value is 'c:\X2SecurityReCalculatorSetup.msi'.
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: Machine policy value 'MsiDisableEmbeddedUI' is 0
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding SourceDir property. Its value is 'c:\'.
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:132]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding SOURCEDIR property. Its value is 'c:\'.
MSI (c) (F4:E8) [12:32:31:132]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding VersionHandler property. Its value is '4.05'.
=== Logging started: 2/23/2011  12:32:31 ===
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:148]: Note: 1: 2262 2: PatchPackage 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:148]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:148]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:148]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding UILevel property. Its value is '5'.
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:148]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ACTION property. Its value is 'INSTALL'.
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:148]: Doing action: INSTALL
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:148]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ActionText 3: -2147287038 
Action 12:32:31: INSTALL. 
Action start 12:32:31: INSTALL.
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:148]: UI Sequence table 'InstallUISequence' is present and populated.
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:148]: Running UISequence
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:148]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding EXECUTEACTION property. Its value is 'INSTALL'.
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:148]: Doing action: DIRCA_CheckFX
Action 12:32:31: DIRCA_CheckFX. 
Action start 12:32:31: DIRCA_CheckFX.
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:148]: Note: 1: 2235 2:  3: ExtendedType 4: SELECT `Action`,`Type`,`Source`,`Target`, NULL, `ExtendedType` FROM `CustomAction` WHERE `Action` = 'DIRCA_CheckFX' 
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:148]: Creating MSIHANDLE (1) of type 790542 for thread 3064
MSI (c) (F4:5C) [12:32:31:148]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\DOCUME~1\nazirj\LOCALS~1\Temp\2\MSI6.tmp, Entrypoint: CheckFX
MSI (c) (F4:38) [12:32:31:163]: Cloaking enabled.
MSI (c) (F4:38) [12:32:31:163]: Attempting to enable all disabled privileges before calling Install on Server
MSI (c) (F4:38) [12:32:31:163]: Connected to service for CA interface.
MSI (c) (F4:5C) [12:32:31:288]: Closing MSIHANDLE (1) of type 790542 for thread 3064
Action ended 12:32:31: DIRCA_CheckFX. Return value 3.
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:288]: Doing action: FatalErrorForm
Action 12:32:31: FatalErrorForm. 
Action start 12:32:31: FatalErrorForm.
MSI (c) (F4:F8) [12:32:31:288]: Note: 1: 2235 2:  3: ExtendedType 4: SELECT `Action`,`Type`,`Source`,`Target`, NULL, `ExtendedType` FROM `CustomAction` WHERE `Action` = 'FatalErrorForm' 
MSI (c) (F4:E8) [12:32:31:288]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
Info 2898. For VSI_MS_Sans_Serif13.0_0_0 textstyle, the system created a 'MS Sans Serif' font, in 0 character set, of 13 pixels height.
MSI (c) (F4:E8) [12:32:31:288]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
DEBUG: Error 2826:  Control Line2 on dialog FatalErrorForm extends beyond the boundaries of the dialog to the right by 3 pixels
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2826. The arguments are: FatalErrorForm, Line2, to the right
MSI (c) (F4:E8) [12:32:31:288]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
DEBUG: Error 2826:  Control BannerBmp on dialog FatalErrorForm extends beyond the boundaries of the dialog to the right by 3 pixels
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2826. The arguments are: FatalErrorForm, BannerBmp, to the right
MSI (c) (F4:E8) [12:32:31:288]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
Info 2898. For VsdDefaultUIFont.524F4245_5254_5341_4C45_534153783400 textstyle, the system created a 'MS Sans Serif' font, in 0 character set, of 13 pixels height.
MSI (c) (F4:E8) [12:32:31:288]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
DEBUG: Error 2826:  Control Line1 on dialog FatalErrorForm extends beyond the boundaries of the dialog to the right by 3 pixels
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2826. The arguments are: FatalErrorForm, Line1, to the right
MSI (c) (F4:E8) [12:32:31:288]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
Info 2898. For VSI_MS_Sans_Serif16.0_1_0 textstyle, the system created a 'MS Sans Serif' font, in 0 character set, of 20 pixels height.
Action 12:32:31: FatalErrorForm. Dialog created
MSI (c) (F4:B8) [12:32:31:288]: Note: 1: 2731 2: 0 
Action ended 12:33:09: FatalErrorForm. Return value 1.
===
```

Answer (score 0):

I kind of solved this for the interim in a very nasty way thou.

I used the ORCA utility to remove the Framework check from the MSI.

DIRCA_CheckFX
VSDCA_VsdLaunchConditions

http://www.technipages.com/download-orca-msi-editor.html
http://www.technipages.com/download-orca-msi-editor.html

The information around the Windows Installer is limited so if anyone can shed light on this, would be much appreciated.